# ASP.NET Login Control - protect from SQLi with Authenticate event?

Tags: asp.net, sql-injection

I have a quick question about the ASP.NET Login control.

I understand that it protects from SQL Injection, but I was wondering if it also protects when I use the "Authenticate" Sub (for a custom authenticate method)?

Can I go ahead and use 'username' and 'password' in an SQL statement without coding them as parameters? Cheers.

Comment: Login control doesn't protect SQL injection, unless you use Membership Provider, Identity, or etc. Please post your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I am using Membership. My only concern is that the inputs are not checked before the "Authenticate" sub executes.
So if this statement is in "Authenticate", is it unsafe?...

SELECT * FROM aspnet_Membership AS A INNER JOIN aspnet_Users AS B ON A.UserId = B.UserId WHERE B.UserName = '" & Login1.UserName & "' AND A.Password = '" & Login1.Password & "';"

Comment: To simplify my last post - is it safe to concatenate the Login1.Username and Login1.Password in an SQL string? (are they validated before the "Authenticate" sub executes?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SELECT * FROM aspnet_Membership AS A INNER JOIN aspnet_Users AS B ON
>   A.UserId = B.UserId WHERE B.UserName = '" & Login1.UserName & "' AND
>   A.Password = '" & Login1.Password & "';"

Above SQL Statement is not safe. It is prone to SQL Injection attack. You want to use parameterized query.

For example,

```
SELECT * 
FROM aspnet_Membership AS A INNER JOIN aspnet_Users AS B 
     ON A.UserId = B.UserId 
WHERE B.UserName = @UserName AND A.Password = @Password
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. I will get to work on the parameters :)